# What does MEMUSER represent in JAVA NATIVEMEMORY INFO?

Tags: java, websphere

I was looking javacore file from IBM WebSphere

```
1MEMUSER       JRE: 739,342,972 bytes / 15509 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--VM: 718,839,900 bytes / 14776 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Classes: 129,963,064 bytes / 2730 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Shared Class Cache: 94,371,904 bytes / 2 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 35,591,160 bytes / 2728 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Memory Manager (GC): 549,890,480 bytes / 1144 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Heap: 536,870,912 bytes / 1 allocation
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 13,019,568 bytes / 1143 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Threads: 30,990,020 bytes / 531 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Stack: 936,880 bytes / 111 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Native Stack: 29,229,056 bytes / 112 allocations.
```

I was unable to find out what does the MEMUSER represent here. What does it Signify ? I tried googling but couldn't find out any thing

Answer (score 0):

It's just the javacore section name, so it doesn't necessarily have meaning.  The section name is intended to be stable (unchanging between different JVM versions) so that parsers can be written.  Those lines should be in the NATIVEMEMINFO section of the javacore, which is described in the [Native memory (NATIVEMEMINFO)](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.70.doc/diag/tools/javadump_tags_nativememinfo.html) section in the Knowledge Center.